# Part of PictureBox under another window gets erased

Tags: vb.net, graphics, buffer, paint, picturebox

I'm using vb.net 2008 express for a spectrum analysis application that draws a spectrum image into a picturebox. I'm using buffered graphics for speed and calling a draw routine from the paint event. For the most part this works fine, but when another window moves over mine, the part that was covered is blank when I return to my window. I have determined that the erasing is happening after the draw routine is called from the picturebox.paint event. If I once again call the drawing routine (in this case caused by Spectra_MouseUp), the image is completely redrawn.

I can't figure out how to keep (or redraw) the entire image after I return to my window.

Relevant parts of my code follows:

```
Private currentContext As BufferedGraphicsContext
Private spectraBuffer As BufferedGraphics

Private Sub DrawSpectra()
    Dim Gr As Graphics

    spectraBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(Spectra.CreateGraphics, Spectra.DisplayRectangle)
    Gr = spectraBuffer.Graphics
    '.
    '.
    '. Lots of drawing stuff here such as.... (yes, everything here is declared)
                If FillSpectra Then
                    Gr.DrawPolygon(BasePen, ptsSpec.ToArray)
                    Gr.FillPolygon(BaseBrush, ptsSpec.ToArray)
                Else
                    Gr.DrawLines(BasePen, ptsSpec.ToArray)
                End If
    '.
    '.
    ' Render the contents of the buffer to the Spectra window.
    spectraBuffer.Render()
End Sub

Private Sub frmMCAWindow_Activated(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
    Call DrawSpectra()
    ' DrawSpectra() works fine from here
End Sub

Private Sub Spectra_MouseUp(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Spectra.MouseUp
    Call DrawSpectra()
End Sub

Private Sub Spectra_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Spectra.Paint
    ' When dragging another window over mine, DrawSpectra() works fine here to keep the image in the picturebox 
    Debug.Print("Begin Spectra_Paint()")
    Call DrawSpectra()
    ' I put a 1 sec. sleep for testing, the image stayed complete while waiting
    ' The part that was covered was erased once the sleep completed.
    Debug.Print("End Spectra_Paint()")
End Sub
```

Comment: windows calls the Paint event to tell your controls to refresh after something passes over them.  with all the Draw code outside the Paint event, that doesnt happen

Comment: You should not be calling CreateGraphics.  You should be using the Graphics instance that is passed into the Paint event in the PaintEventArgs.  Try passing that into your DrawSpectra method.  Also, a PictureBox is not really designed for this type of drawing.  Perhaps it would be better to draw directly on the Form or onto a Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Chris. Turns out using Spectra.CreateGraphics instead of the PaintEventArgs (for e.Graphics) was the issue. I reworked to the following & it works perfectly now.

```
Private currentContext As BufferedGraphicsContext
Private spectraBuffer As BufferedGraphics

Private Sub frmMCAWindow_Activated(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
    Spectra.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub Spectra_MouseUp(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Spectra.MouseUp
    Spectra.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub Spectra_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Spectra.Paint
    Dim Gr As Graphics

    spectraBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(e.Graphics, Spectra.DisplayRectangle)
    Gr = spectraBuffer.Graphics
    '.
    '.
    '. Lots of drawing stuff here such as....
            If FillSpectra Then
                Gr.DrawPolygon(BasePen, ptsSpec.ToArray)
                Gr.FillPolygon(BaseBrush, ptsSpec.ToArray)
            Else
                Gr.DrawLines(BasePen, ptsSpec.ToArray)
            End If
    '.
    '.
    ' Render the contents of the buffer to the Spectra window.
    spectraBuffer.Render()
End Sub
```